# Is not a function error - JavaScript es6 class structure

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

having issue - is not function error, with my code, here it is:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import gsap from 'greensock';

class IntroAnimations{
 constructor(){
    this.ctaEnter         = $('#cta-enter');
    this.loadContent      = $('.center-h-v');
    this.tlLoading        = new TimelineLite();
    this.animationTime    = .5;

    this.ctaEnter.click(function(){
        this.removeLoadContent(); //<- error is here
    })
 }
removeLoadContent(){
    TweenLite.to(this.loadContent, this.animationTime, {autoAlpha: 0})
 }
}

export default IntroAnimations;
```

Error is when I call this.removeLoadContent();
Can someone help me explain why this is causing an error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.ctaEnter.click(() => {
    this.removeLoadContent(); //<- error was here
})
```

Comment: This worked but how and why?

Comment: @harp you should probably read more about javascripts context...

Answer (score 0):

This is because "this" has different context.

Write your function using the fat arrow and it should works.

```
removeLoadContent = ()=>{
    TweenLite.to(this.loadContent, this.animationTime, {autoAlpha: 0})
 }
```